# How can i mock this

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I need to mock this objects, but i dont how.

I edited the test:

```
LinkedList<String> listExemptCookies = Mockito.mock(LinkedList.class);
    when((List<String>) portletSession.getAttribute("exemptCookiesListSession")).thenReturn(listExemptCookies);
    when(new LinkedList<String>(configPortlet.getExemptCookiesList(request))).thenReturn(listExemptCookies);
```

and this is the code:

```
List<String> listExemptCookies = new LinkedList<String>(getExemptCookiesList(request));
```

getExemptCookiesList return a arraylist, i mocked it in the first when..but gives me nullPointerException when try the last it..

Comment: Do you really have two List<String>s named `exemtpCookiesList` and `listExemptCookies` in the same function?

Comment: I don't think you ever need to mock a list.  Can't you use a real one?

Comment: BTW, even if you could, a constructor will NEVER return null.

Comment: I have two list with different implementation because i need to do call a .contains method with a string, and this is possible only with a linkedlist and not with arraylist.

Comment: The null return is for the example, its not my real code.
And how can i test if the object its added correctly?

Comment: Could you post the whole test, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powermock to mock the LinkedList constructor. See the usage details [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects)